# Compressing Folder via Batch file and VBScript

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, compression

I'm trying to compress a folder without any third-party tools using a batch file to call a VBScript.

However, I am getting an error.

Sample of Script (Batch):

```
@echo off

REM: Copy files from Current Dir to another

set CurrMonth=%date%
set CurrMonth=%CurrMonth:~3,2%

ECHO %CurrMonth%

set PathDir=".\Mon%CurrMonth%"

ECHO %PathDir%

timeout /t 5 /nobreak

ECHO "Copying files"

CScript zip.vbs ".\Mon" ".\%PathDir%.zip"

REM: xcopy /e ".\Mon" "%PathDir%.zip"

PAUSE
```

The idea is to call the VBScript that will take folder "Mon" and Zip it to the same location as Mon[CurrentMonth].zip.

VBScript:

```
'Get command-line arguments.
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
InputFolder = objArgs(0)
ZipFile = objArgs(1)

'Create empty ZIP file.
CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ZipFile, True).Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, vbNullChar)

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Set source = objShell.NameSpace(InputFolder).Items

objShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).CopyHere(source)

'Required!
wScript.Sleep 2000
```

When running this script, it generates the correct Zip file. However, it throws an error...

"D:...\zip.vbs(11, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required: 'objShell.NameSpace(...)'"

Any thoughts?

Solution:

```
Dim CurrentDirectory
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set app = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

' Getting date and weekday for Dynamic Pathing

CurrDate = Date()
CurrWeekday = WeekdayName(Weekday(CurrDate,2),True,2)
CurrStamp = CurrWeekday & "_" & Month(Date) & "_" & Year(Date)

' Get Current Path

CurrentDirectory = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)

' Set Target Zip Path

zipfile = CurrentDirectory & "\" & CurrStamp & ".zip"

' Set Source Path

fldr    = CurrentDirectory & "\" & CurrWeekday

' Set Counter of files in Source

cnt     = fso.GetFolder(fldr).Files.Count

' Creating the Target

fso.OpenTextFile(zipfile, 2, True).Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) _
  & String(18, Chr(0))

' Copy from Source to Target

Set zip = app.NameSpace(zipfile)
zip.CopyHere app.NameSpace(fldr).Items

' Loop and Sleep to Ensure Completed
Do
    
    WScript.Sleep 100

Loop Until zip.Items.Count = cnt
```

Comment: This line of code: `CScript zip.vbs ".\Mon" ".\%PathDir%.zip"` executes as `CScript zip.vbs ".\Mon" ".\".\Mon10".zip"`

Comment: Thank you, I added that ./ by mistake second time testing. I have removed it again so it resolves to .\Mon10.zip

However, still get the same error. It seems more like something in the VBScript? as it's not able to establish the path via the arg?

Comment: Problem resolved. Was silly me not having a "\" between the dir and the Zip file name.

Working as expected now